# PTR to domain, A record for domain

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record, ptr-record, rfc

Does PTR pointing to domain is forbidden? If so - which RFC states that. The same with A record pointing at the domain. As I see, usually, people are trying to avoid such configurations. But I would like to be precise here. Is it forbidden or not. Thanks.

Example:
funnydomain.com.     3600 IN A 146.243.6.1

and

1.6.243.146.in-addr.arpa. 7200 IN PTR funnydomain.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is completely valid. There is no problem with that at all - it is a very very common configuration.

The main thing you should not do on a domain, but can do on a hostname, is setting a CNAME. This because on the domain name, there will always be NS records and those can never be combined with a CNAME.

Comment: I have found it very useful to use A records for physical hosts and CNAME records for services (such as websites, ftp sites, VPN sites, etc.) In that way I can easily move a service from one host to another and it is visible which host a particular service or site is located on.

Comment: I do the same, most of the time :)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. In this topic I would like to be perfectly precise.
@wolfgangsz yes - it is very good habit. Moreover if you have a environement with huge amount of devices, it is good to create additional level of abstraction within domain name scope and have subdomains like: web.somedomain.com (all web services), sec.somedomain.com (all security services) etc.

Answer (score 1):

A PTR record is just an additional information.
Some sites / e-mailsystems require correct ptr setups.

- An A record points from a domainname/hostname to an ip.
- An PRT record points from an ip to an domainname/hostname

It's a good option to have both, but you need at least an A record.

RFC's for DNS:

http://www.dns.net/dnsrd/rfc/